# Splash screen leaking memory how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, memory, splash-screen

My Splash screen leaking memory can anyone tell me how to fix that issue ?

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new InnerClass(SplashActivity.this).loadNext();
}

private static class InnerClass {
    private final WeakReference<Activity> weakReference;

    private InnerClass(Activity activity) {
        this.weakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    private void loadNext() {
        Activity context = weakReference.get();
        if (context != null) {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NavigationActivity.class));
                    context.finish();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the leak canary library report showing your activity leaking memory
[image: here is the leak canary library report showing your activity leaking memory]

Answer (score 0):

Move the `weakReference.get()` method inside the `run()` method. Please try below:

```
private void loadNext() {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Activity context = weakReference.get();
                    if (context != null) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NavigationActivity.class));
                    context.finish();
                   }
                }
            }, 2000);
         }
```

Comment: thank you I will do but can you tell please suggest me any other best approach ?