# Inner class leaking memory in android java?

Tags: java, android, memory, splash-screen

I've created an inner class having weakreference to outer activity class but stills it's leaking memory. I'm stuck out of this can anybody help me in this ?

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new InnerClass(SplashActivity.this).loadNext();
}

private static class InnerClass   {
    private final WeakReference<Activity> weakReference;

    public InnerClass(Activity activity) {
        this.weakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    private void loadNext() {
        Activity context = weakReference.get();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (context != null) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NavigationActivity.class));
                    context.finish();
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please check my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62877267/splash-screen-leaking-memory-how-to-fix-it/62877435#62877435

Comment: yes I used that approach in my app but it's still leaking memory

Comment: I just copied that code and put weakReference.get() inside the method but I'm still facing leaking. GC not releasing the instance.